# convert string to Mysql time stamp in servlet java

Tags: java, mysql, apache, java-server

hi i am passing my date time string using get method in apache servlet and it goes like this

```
http://localhost:8084/example/Time_ser?date=15/03/2013%2004:14:30%20PM
```

and i am using

```
String time=request.getParameter("date");
```

to get the date value.....

and my java code to convert the string to timestamp is given below

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
java.util.Date date = (java.util.Date)formatter.parse(time);
Timestamp timets = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

but it shows error like this

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "15/03/2013 04:14:30 PM"
```

am i doing anything wrong please help me..........

Comment: The answer below is correct. Also, you don't neeed that cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `/` not `-` because you date is formatted as `15/03/2013 04:14:30 PM`.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
```